# Get Cell ID within a lat long range

Tags: geolocation, latitude-longitude, cellid

Is it possible to get cell id of all the networks by providing a particular range of latitude and longitude?

For example if I am giving a latitude range of 10 to 30 and longitude range of 70 to 80 the output must show all the cell id code along with mcc, mnc, lac codes.

Comment: Need more details. Are you working with a telecom provider? To they release these information?

Comment: no i dont work with telecom provider, They dont release these data but there are various sites and google that accumulate this information. they can get lat long values from cellid. i want just the reversed of it.

Comment: If such data are publicly available then I guess you can build a database out of them.